can't change filename to Korean on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
https://youtu.be/ejQcqA0ciCA
<- this is my recorded video
As the title says, when I create files and folders I can input Korean, but when I rename files and folders only English is input. If I copy Korean from somewhere else and paste it Korean is applied well. (This problem does not occur in Ubuntu 24.10) Can I get help to figure out how to fix this?
